# How to structure models in Ruby on Rails for game lineups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, ruby-on-rails-5, model-associations

Super noob with Ruby on Rails so any feedback/guidance is **greatly** appreciated!

```
rails -v && ruby -v # Rails 5.0.2 ruby 2.4.1p111
```

I'm building a game lineup app where a user can add a player on a game roster and then generate a table of lineups. For instance, a player's lineup for a baseball game where each inning shows what position the player will have for that inning.

The way I have created my models are as follows...

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :roster, required: false
    has_many :innings, inverse_of: :player
    has_many :positions, through: :innings
end

class Inning < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :player, required: false
    has_many :positions, inverse_of: :player
end

class Position < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :inning
end
```

Would this work out the desired way? Something feels off about this but I can't quite pin point it. I've looked into several ways to handling this with a many-to-many association but even that doesn't sound quite right.

Let me know what you guys think, thanks for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: seems right, have you tried creating data in rails console and seeing if it works as intended?

Comment: Yup! Looks like it does give me what I want. I'm just pretty unfamiliar with database associations. Thanks @maxple